# SQL Server 2012 Sequence Object

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequences

Here is my sample table, the primary key is a composite key of Akey+Bkey

```
Akey  Bkey  ItemSequence    
----  ----  ------------
1     1     1
1     5     2
1     7     3
2     7     1
3     2     1
3     3     2
```

Akey is generated from a SQL 2012 Sequence object ASequence.  In most cases I insert one row at a time and when necessary I call NEXT VALUE FOR ASequence.  However I need to do an insert from a statement like:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Something) as AKey,
    Bkey, Sequence
FROM TABLEB
```

The OVER clause of the NEXT VALUE does not work this way as I need to be able to insert records as a SET but only increment the Sequence once per DENSE_RANK set.
So we have the ALTER SEQUENCE command and with this I am able to set the sequence to what I want.  The caveat to this is that it must be a constant and will not accept a variable.  My workaround to this was:

```
DECLARE @startingID INT
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @newSeed INT

SET @startingID = NEXT VALUE FOR ASequence

INSERT TABLEA
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Something) + @startingID as AKey,
    Bkey, Sequence
FROM TABLEB

SELECT @newSeed = MAX(Akey) FROM TABLEA

SET @sql = ‘ALTER SEQUENCE ASEQUENCE RESTART WITH ‘ + cast(@newSeed+1 as varchar(10))
EXEC(@sql)
```

Seems terrible to have DML statements in Dynamic SQL like this.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The solution provided by Vlad is the way to go.  However if you MUST use dynamic SQL in the future make sure to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of EXEC.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
INSERT TABLEA
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR ASequence OVER(ORDER BY Something) as AKey,
    Bkey, Seq
FROM TABLEB
```

Comment: Did you try your code?  It will not work this way. THE OVER clause of NEXT VALUE only applies to sorting.  It specifies the order in which the sequence is applied, per row.  I need the sequence to provide 1 value per set as described in my question.  After much research I concluded this was not possible other than the way I have detailed.  I was hoping someone could prove me wrong in my findings.  At first glace you would think the NEXT VALUE would work this way and also seems like a logical feature.

Comment: See if sp_sequence_get_range sounds better to you than dynamic DDL. In either case this code will produce incorrect results when run from multiple connections simultaneously.

Comment: Do you mind me asking, why do you care if AKey increments per rank group or per record? Can you just treat it as the PK in TableA and use straight identity (or sequence)?

Comment: Because the table has a composite key of AKey+BKey.  I will never argue that this was the right table design decision that was made but I cannot change that.  There are many frustrations with keys treated this way.  If nothing else I have learned much about XML PATH is a savior due to it's ability to pivot these tables. But since this is an attempt to do an insert into the table I do not believe a sequence supports this kind of operation.  The other thing I could do is to enter a loop of distinct AKeys and call NEXT VALUE that many times.  It is hacky.

Comment: @Jeff - sp_sequence_get_range allows you to add an arbitrary number to the sequence.

Comment: So the question is how do I then update the sequence with it's new value?  Having an ALTER statement as well as having that dynamic is unnatural and ugly as well as opens the doors for security to have to be defined implicitly to allow this to happen.

Comment: sp_sequence_get_range returns a batch of sequence numbers AND updates the sequence to the new number that is (last number in the batch) + 1

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  This is the answer that I was looking for.  Thanks for sticking with this and talking through it with me. This absolutely does away with the DDL and the dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Or, how about this:

```
CREATE TABLEA
(
    GroupID INT,
    AKey INT,
    BKey INT,
    ItemSequence INT, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_TABLEA PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        GroupID,
        AKey,
        BKey 
    )
)

DECLARE @GroupID INT
SET @GroupID = NEXT VALUE FOR ASequence

INSERT TABLEA
SELECT @GroupID, DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY Something) as AKey,
    Bkey, Sequence
FROM TABLEB
```

and if you need the value of AKey as it is in your example, you can do GroupID+AKey here.